# Extract value from control in ControlToValidate property in a CustomValidator control?

Tags: asp.net, validation

How do get the value in the JavaScript function identified in `ClientValidationFunction` property that was entered in the control that was identified in the `ControlToValidate` property of a `asp:CustomValidator` control?

```
function MyValidateFunction(sender, args) {
    //want to get value of MyControl    
}

<asp:CustomValidator 
    ID="cvAlarmedLocationAddress" 
    runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="MyControl" 
    ClientValidationFunction="MyValidateFunction" 
    Text="" 
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of the `args.Value` property in your javascript. Here is a C# example from the MSDN library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx#Y570