# How to get ControlToValidate control inside validation function when a validation function is used for multiple controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, validation

Ok,

This seems straight forward but I am having trouble finding the solution.

I have 10 `PeopleEditor` controls. Each one of the `PeopleEditor` controls has a `CustomValidator` and the `ControlToValidate` property is set to that specific `PeopleEditor` control. I assign a function to the control based on criteria.

It is possible that the same validation function is assigned to multiple `CustomValidator`s which in turn means the function needs to know which `ControlToValidate` control it is validating.

Is this clear?

The question is:
How do I reference the control from the `ControlToValidate` property in the validation function server side c# code?

Here are similar issues but they reference client side or inline validation:
[How to get the 'controlToValidate' property on ClientValidationFunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636228/asp-net-custom-validator-how-to-get-the-controltovalidate-property-on-clientv) and 
[Extract value from control in ControlToValidate property in a CustomValidator control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880418/extract-value-from-control-in-controltovalidate-property-in-a-customvalidator-co)

**UPDATE:**
I have 10 of these in the `.aspx` page:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPeople0" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="edtPeople0" SelectionSet="User,SecGroup" AutoPostBack="false" CausesValidation="false" PlaceButtonsUnderEntityEditor="false" Rows="3" AllowEmpty="true" ValidatorVisible="true" runat="server" MultiSelect="true" MaximumEntities="100" ShowCreateButtonInActiveDirectoryAccountCreationMode="true" />
<asp:CustomValidator id="vldPeople0" display="Dynamic" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Error Message." ControlToValidate="edtPeople0" />
```

In the `.aspx.cs` page, I assign the validating function like this:

```
vldPeople0.ServerValidate += new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventHandler(validate_ThisAndThat);
```

Then, I have this for the function and need to get the `ControlToValidate` in order get the `ResolvedEntities` from it.

```
/// <summary>
/// Validation function.
/// </summary>
private void validate_ThisAndThat(Object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
  foreach (PickerEntity entity in (ControlToValidate).ResolvedEntities)
  {
    String tmpPrincipalType = (entity.EntityData["PrincipalType"]).ToString();

    if (tmpPrincipalType == "User")
    {
      if ((entity.EntityData["DisplayName"]).ToString().Contains("aString"))
      {
        args.IsValid = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the key was to assign an attribute to the `CustomValidator`...

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPeople0" runat="server" />
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor ID="edtPeople0" SelectionSet="User,SecGroup" AutoPostBack="false" CausesValidation="false" PlaceButtonsUnderEntityEditor="false" Rows="3" AllowEmpty="true" ValidatorVisible="true" runat="server" MultiSelect="true" MaximumEntities="100" ShowCreateButtonInActiveDirectoryAccountCreationMode="true" />
<asp:CustomValidator id="vldPeople0" display="Dynamic" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Error Message." ControlToValidate="edtPeople0" />
```

In the `.aspx.cs` page, I assign the validating function like this:

```
vldPeople0.ServerValidate += new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventHandler(validate_ThisAndThat);
vldPeople0.Attributes.Add("peopleEditor", "edtPeople0");
```

Then, I have this for the function.

```
private void validate_ThisAndThat(Object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
  CustomValidator thisValidator = (CustomValidator) source;
  string strPeopleEditor = (string)thisValidator.Attributes["peopleEditor"];
  PeopleEditor peopleEditor = (PeopleEditor)panel1.FindControl(strPeopleEditor);

  foreach (PickerEntity entity in peopleEditor.ResolvedEntities)
  {
    String tmpPrincipalType = (entity.EntityData["PrincipalType"]).ToString();

    if (tmpPrincipalType == "User")
    {
      if ((entity.EntityData["DisplayName"]).ToString().Contains("aString"))
      {
        args.IsValid = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do.  The OnServerValidate definition can point to the same method (handler).  You can cast the sender of the ServerValidateEventArgs to find the object type and ID.  Alternatively, give each validator its own callback, and define a central set of validation methods called from each of the callbacks.  This way, the logic is in common methods is called for the appropriate handler.

HTH.

Comment: Brian. I really appreciate the answer but I am not following it... Perhaps I need clarify my answer...